# Get all dates of current month using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, calendar, range

I want to print all dates of current month like this

```
2019-06-1
2019-06-2
2019-06-3
2019-06-4
2019-06-5
...
2019-06-28
2019-06-29
2019-06-30
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2019, 6, 1)
d2 = date(2019, 6, 30)
delta = d2 - d1

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print(d1 + timedelta(days=i))
```

---

Refining the code and making it independent of user specification:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import calendar

def all_dates_current_month():
    month = datetime.now().month
    year = datetime.now().year
    number_of_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    first_date = date(year, month, 1)
    last_date = date(year, month, number_of_days)
    delta = last_date - first_date

    return [(first_date + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(delta.days + 1)]

all_dates_current_month()
```

and you get:

```
['2019-06-01',
 '2019-06-02',
 '2019-06-03',
 '2019-06-04',
 '2019-06-05',
 '2019-06-06',
 '2019-06-07',
 '2019-06-08',
 '2019-06-09',
 '2019-06-10',
 '2019-06-11',
 '2019-06-12',
 '2019-06-13',
 '2019-06-14',
 '2019-06-15',
 '2019-06-16',
 '2019-06-17',
 '2019-06-18',
 '2019-06-19',
 '2019-06-20',
 '2019-06-21',
 '2019-06-22',
 '2019-06-23',
 '2019-06-24',
 '2019-06-25',
 '2019-06-26',
 '2019-06-27',
 '2019-06-28',
 '2019-06-29',
 '2019-06-30']
```

Comment: Sure, I am going to refine the code. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

[`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) will tell you how many days that month has (considering leap years, etc). From there, you'll need a bunch of scaffolding to create the range:

```
from calendar import monthrange

def allDays(y, m):
    return ['{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(y, m, d) for d in range(1, monthrange(y, m)[1] + 1)]
```